# Seek Commandline syntax to add Windows Firewall w/Advanced Services rule

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-firewall

The last time I stepped into the GUI to block a 'intrusion-attempting' IP I mucked up my remote access due to a misclick. Would like to avoid that again.

Looking for either a direct-from-cmd command or powershell script that will block all incoming attempts from a given IP.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In newer version of Windows (Server 2012 R2 or Windows 8+) you should use Powershell as netsh is deprecated:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831755.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try "netsh advfirewall firewall". The displayed help-text will fill you up with what you are looking for.